# Finding the Chromatic Polynomial for a given graph.

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, coloring

[triangle graph with one chord inside from the top to the base and the base is extended to one node outside on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmIMr.png)

I have this question in a sample paper. I am not able to figure out how to find the chromatic polynomial for this figure. I was able to somewhat get a mental answer using just plain logic but I doubt that would work in an actual exam answer. I tried decomposition but I don't know if I am doing it right. Been breaking my head trying to figure it out but found no help online or on youtube with anything similar to this type of question. Any and all help is appreciated as I have my paper in 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

The three nodes $x,y,t$ form a complete graph $K_3$, for which the chromatic polynomial is $k(k-1)(k-2)$.  Now $w$ can be any color different from $x$, yielding another factor of $k-1$.  Also, $z$ must be different from both $t$ and $y$ (which are different colors), yielding another factor of $k-2$.  Hence, the chromatic polynomial is $k(k-1)^2(k-2)^2$.